# Named after my creation—what am I?

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

I thought of a riddle:

> Named after my creation
>   
> By ones in need, or ones of station
>   
> With bowing bays I wind and light
>   
> With barreling wagons I leap to a height
>   
> Though I cannot fly, my wings do protect
>   
> Through passing ages I paths correct
>
> Mess up my plans and pay a terrible cost
>   
> Make me confused and all will be lost
>
> I'm in impossible dreams of tomorrow's Rome
>   
> I'm in Jesus shunning sand when placing a home
>   
> I'm in trucks and tanks that were made to stay
>   
> In one of my senses, or so they might say
>
> Yet does the gate to my name allow ingress?
>   
> What am I—process, result, and progress?

The answer is a single English word.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! Looks like a nice first riddle :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think the answer is

> Building.

Named after my creation

> A building comes about as a result of building.

By ones in need,

> Building society. (OP addition: Shelter is a basic human need.)

or ones of station

> Master builders. (OP addition: Some buildings are built as status symbols; a station is a type of building.)

With bowing bays I wind and light

> I think this refers to bow windows and bay windows found on some buildings to provide more light.

With barreling wagons I leap to a height

> I think this refers to a [barrel vault](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barrel_vault) (also called a **wagon** vault) found in some buildings and usually forms part of the roof or ceiling. (OP addition: "Leap" is another word for "vault", if used as a verb.)

Though I cannot fly, my wings do protect

> Buildings can have [wings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wing_(building)) which, among other functions, can provide shorter escape routes in safety-critical buildings.

Through passing ages I paths correct

> This refers to road building to create paths which has been done throughout the ages.  (OP addition: Also, passing ages → passages i.e. corridors guide people through buildings.)

Mess up my plans and pay a terrible cost

> Mess up the plans for a building and it could prove very costly.

Make me confused and all will be lost

> I think confused here is a synonym for "unlisted" and unlisted buildings are not protected against demolition. (OP note: It's easy to get lost in confusing buildings.)

I'm in impossible dreams of tomorrow's Rome

> "Rome wasn't **built** in a day" (OP note: Also, impossible dreams are "**building** castles in the sky")

I'm in Jesus shunning sand when placing a home

> This refers to the [Parable of Wise and Foolish Builders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parable_of_the_Wise_and_the_Foolish_Builders)

I'm in trucks

> Building trucks (OP note: and "built like a truck")

and tanks that were made to stay

> I think this refers to things like water tanks found in many buildings. (OP note: or "built like a tank")

In one of my senses, or so they might say

> Building site (sounds like 'sight') (OP note: Also, alluding to how the previous parts of the paragraph are **sayings** or idioms, all using the "to build" **sense** of the word.)

Yet does the gate to my name allow ingress?

> Possibly a reference to the [Red Gate Building](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Gate_Building) which at one point house the Ministry of Transport Construction. (OP note: "Yett", "gate" and "ingress" are all words for entranceways.)

What am I—process, result, and progress?

> Building is a verb and a noun referring to a structure and also the action of constructing something. (OP note: As well as the progress of something e.g. "the building suspense".)

Comment: Oh, very nice! I wasn't convinced at first, but this fits all of the clues - I especially like the Rome line. Looks perfect :-)

Comment: You got it! Is it customary here for a riddle-asker to edit the accepted answer's explanations of the clues to fill in details? You have some explanations here that I hadn't thought of, but which work great—I would of course preserve them.

Comment: @Anko If you note that they are your edits (e.g. `O.P. EDIT:`), I don't think there's a problem.

Comment: Yes, I have no problem with you editing @Anko